# Is there an expiration date on Bank of America's Cashiers checks?

Tags: united-states, banking, cashier-check

Upon my advice, my daughter requested a cashiers check in a BOA office in NJ today rather than carry a sum of cash out of the bank. She asked how long the check was valid. The Bank Manager told her they expire in 90 days. I told her my own personal checks are good for 180 days before they are stale dated.

- Why are banks cashiers checks only valid for half that time? I know they do not expire or become stale dated.
- The bank issues these checks based on good and valid funds in their bank and usually do not print an expiration date on them.
- Why would a Bank of America tell ones of its customers this incorrect information?

Comment: "Is there an expiration date?", asks the title. "I know they do not expire", says the body. If you know the answer, why are you asking us?

Comment: http://www.tdbank.com/tdhelps/default.aspx/if-i-write-a-check-to-someone-how-long-do-they-have-to-cash-it-before-it-expires/v/39020541/ or just google "do checks expire" (no quotes)

Answer (score 2):

> Why are banks cashiers checks only valid for half that time? I know they do not expire or become stale dated.

Generally yes, they do not expire or become stale. However quite a few Banks impose a date. This is done to discharge their liability and encourage to encash the check at the earliest. It also makes it easier for the Banks to carry and monitor activities like Stop's [i.e. you daughter says the check was misplaced] or lost and your daughter needs to go back to BOA and request the funds or a new check.

> The bank issues these checks based on good and valid funds in their bank and usually do not print an expiration date on them.

Some Banks do put a date, again for above reasons.

> Why would a Bank of America tell ones of its customers this incorrect information?

If its stamped on the check, its correct information. If not, it may just be a way to encourage to cash the check at earliest.